# A currying function

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I have:

```
- fun F p q = p q;
val F = fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b
```

I know how to use it, for example by first having `fun square x = x*x` and then invoking `F Sq 3`.  However, I don't quite understand the function expression in the second line.   Can someone help paraphrase it in English and indicating which parameter is `'a` and which is `'b'`.

Answer (score 0):

`F` here is a so called *higher-order function* which has two arguments:

- `p` which has type `'a -> 'b` (so it's a function!)
- `q` which has type `'a`
- `F` (if applied first to an `'a -> 'b` and then to an `'a` produces an `b

The second line just tells you exactly this.

Moreover you know what is does: it plugs in `q` into `p`! (it applys `p` to `q`)

Your example of course is:

- `square: int -> int` (so `'a` and `'b` here need both to be `int` as you use `square` in place of `q`)
- `3` which has type `int` so the expression `F square 3` is wellformed

It evaluates as:

```
F square 3
{ def F }
= square 3
{ def square }
= 3*3
{ arithmetic }
= 9
```

Comment: I am still a bit confused.  Where does it say ('a->'b)->`'a`->'b?  Why not ('a->'b)->`'c`->'b? That is, why does `F p` result in the same type as the input type of `p`?

Comment: Because of the body: `p q` - as you apply ´p` to `q` the domain of `p` needs to have the same type as `q` or this would not work - to the same reason the result must be the co-domain of `p` (why do you accept the `'b` there?)

Comment: Since `->` is right-associative, the type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b` can be read with the extra set of parentheses as `('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b)`. That is, F can be seen as a function that takes a function and returns it (F is the identity function for functions of one argument).